# Titanium showCamera and OpenPhotoGallery Function

Tags: titanium

I wish to ask is there anyone face the problem when you guys activate showCamera and open photo Gallery function of titanium in android. It will crash the app and restart app automatically. I have searched a lot of forum especially JIRA appcelator and titanium forum but most of the cases are unresolved. I have tried a lot of method in the forum but still the same. I wish to know is this a bug of titanium?

Comment: By the way Stefan, which SDK version are you using?? If possible please provide some code, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The best code to choose from camera or gallery

```
//Create a dialog with options
var dialog = Titanium.UI.createOptionDialog({
    //title of dialog
    title: 'Choose an image source...',
    //options
    options: ['Camera','Photo Gallery', 'Cancel'],
    //index of cancel button
    cancel:2
});
 
//add event listener
dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    //if first option was selected
    if(e.index == 0)
    {
        //then we are getting image from camera
        Titanium.Media.showCamera({
            //we got something
            success:function(event)
            {
                //getting media
                var image = event.media; 
                 
                //checking if it is photo
                if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
                {
                    //we may create image view with contents from image variable
                    //or simply save path to image
                    Ti.App.Properties.setString("image", image.nativePath);
                }
            },
            cancel:function()
            {
                //do somehting if user cancels operation
            },
            error:function(error)
            {
                //error happend, create alert
                var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera'});
                //set message
                if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA)
                {
                    a.setMessage('Device does not have camera');
                }
                else
                {
                    a.setMessage('Unexpected error: ' + error.code);
                }
 
                // show alert
                a.show();
            },
            allowImageEditing:true,
            saveToPhotoGallery:true
        });
    }
    else if(e.index == 1)
    {
        //obtain an image from the gallery
        Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
            success:function(event)
            {
                //getting media
                var image = event.media; 
                // set image view
                 
                //checking if it is photo
                if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
                {
                    //we may create image view with contents from image variable
                    //or simply save path to image
                    Ti.App.Properties.setString("image", image.nativePath); 
                }   
            },
            cancel:function()
            {
                //user cancelled the action fron within
                //the photo gallery
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //cancel was tapped
        //user opted not to choose a photo
    }
});
 
//show dialog
dialog.show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code for opening the camera and it works correctly:

```
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({

        success:function(event)
        {
            //getting media
            var image = event.media;
            im=image;
            //checking if it is photo
            if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
            {
                imgpath= image.nativePath;
                $.userphoto.image=imgpath;//$.userphoto is an imageview
            }
        },
        cancel:function()
        {
            //do somehting 
        },
        error:function(error)
        {
            //error happened,
            var a = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Camera'});
            //set message
            if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA)
            {
                alert('No Cam');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('error');
            }

        },
        mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
    });
}
```

and this is the code i use for opening the photo gallery (also works fine):

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        success:function(event)
        {

            //check if  photo
            if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
            {   
                im=resize(event.media); //just a function to resize the photo
                imgpath= event.media.nativePath;

                $.userphoto.image=imgpath;
            }  
        },
        cancel:function()
        {
            //user cancelled 
        }
    });
```

By the way now i'm using Titanium SDK 3.4.1 GA, but it also used to work on 3.1.3GA